# Append two times after each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, appendto

I've got this input search with autocomplete. It append image plus label to ul in list and that works just fine. But I also would like to append just the image to a div named wrapper. I'm a begginer in this, can you have two different append after each other?

heres my code:

```
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper"
            <div id="project-label">Select:</div>
            <img id="project-icon" src="images/transparent_1x1.png" class="ui-state-default" alt="">

            <input id="project">
            <input type="hidden" id="project-id" value="flower">
            <p id="project-description"></p>

        </wrapper> 
</body>

<script>
     $(function () {
       var projects = [
            {
                value: "Flower",
                label: "Flower",
                desc: "Beautiful flowers",
                icon: "flower.jpeg"
            },
            {
                value: "Rose",
                label: "R",
                desc: "roses are red violets are blue",
                icon: "rose.jpg"
            },
            {
                value: "Tulip",
                label: "tulip",
                desc: "lalala",
                icon: "tulip.jpg"
            }
        ];

        $( "#project" ).autocomplete({
          minLength: 1,
          source: projects,
          focus: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );
            return false;
          },
          select: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#project" ).val( ui.item.label );
            $( "#project-id" ).val( ui.item.value );
            $( "#project-description" ).html( ui.item.desc );
            $( "#project-icon" ).attr( "src", "img/" + ui.item.icon );

            return false;
          }
        })
        .autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
          return $( "<li>" )

          .append("<a><img src='img/" + item.icon + "' />" + item.label + "</a>")
            .appendTo(ul)

</script>
```

so what I would like is to have another append after the first one like this:

```
  .autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
          return $( "<li>" )
    .append("<a><img src='img/" + item.icon + "' />" + item.label + "</a>")
            .appendTo(ul)

.append("<a><img src='img/" + item.icon + "' />" + "</a>")
        .appendTo(".wrapper")
```

This doesnt work obviously, but can you modify it so that it works?

Comment: If you're using jQuery, add the tag to your question please.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this line in your _renderItem function if you would like to have two entries for one item:

```
return $("<li><a><img src='img/" + item.icon + "' />" + item.label + "</a></li><li><a><img src='img/" + item.icon + "' />" + "</a></li>").appendTo(ul);
```

Comment: thanks, but that only appendTo (ul), I want to append the image to  the div ".wrapper". i.e I want to append ("<a><img src='img/" + item.icon + "' />" + item.label + "</a>" to (ul) AND append ("<a><img src='img/" + item.icon + "' />" + "</a>") to (".wrapper")

Comment: As shown in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Loyr4k40/ you can do anything with the data just before the return statement, e.g. insert http://jsfiddle.net/Loyr4k40/ Although I am sure what you are trying to accomplish with that. You might want to have a look at the create event (http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-create) if you want to place a modified copy of the list somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you! exactly what I wanted! :-)